# Alarm Manager to trigger event daily at particular time specified by me using a String

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I want to trigger an event when clock ticks 9:00 AM 
and again I want trigger another event when clock ticks 4:30 PM, this should be done daily, when user enables it(like using toggle button to enable/disable this feature).

Comment: If `setRepeating()` does't meet your specific needs, then you'll likely have to write your own code (e.g., using `Handler`).

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to [this](http://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/)

But, if you have a repetitive task in your Android app, you need to consider that activities and services can be terminated by the Android system to free up resources. Therefore you can not rely on standard Java schedule like the TimerTasks (AlarmManager) class.

```
<service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:label="some_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >

</service>
<receiver android:name="MyStartServiceReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This should be in your java class:

```
public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TestJobService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
        builder.setMinimumLatency(1 * 1000); // wait at least
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 1000); // maximum delay
        //builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED); // require unmetered network
        //builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true); // device should be idle
        //builder.setRequiresCharging(false); // we don't care if the device is charging or not
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    }
```

Create another class to Start the Service and Listen :

```
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Util.scheduleJob(context);
    }
}
```

This is what will tell the service to start and the Parameters.

```
public class TestJobService extends JobService {
    private static final String TAG = "SyncService";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocalWordService.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(service);
        Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to implement this feature in my app, but not using other app.

Comment: @HimamshKilubatla please see new answer